# "no comprendió la razón hasta no ver ...": is the second "no" necessary?

Tags: gramática

I have questions in this sentence:

> La encontró más bella y juvenil que nunca, pero irrecuperable, como
> nunca, aunque no comprendió la razón hasta no ver la curva de su
> vientre bajo la túnica de seda: estaba encinta de seis meses.

My questions are:

1. The "no" in "hasta no ver" necessary? I feel it is different
   from double negation.
2. If I simply remove the "no" in "hasta no ver", is the sentence
   correct and natural?
3. I understand that hasta is a preposition that needs a noun after
   it, and the Spanish verb functions like an infinitive, but is that
   natural to say "until to see ..."?
4. Since the verb has a noun form, is it better to say "hasta la
   vista de la curva ..."?
5. Or is it better to use the clause form "hasta que vio la curva
   ..."?
6. Or is it better to use the gerund form "hasta viendo la curva ..."?

Sorry that I have a lot of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. and 2.

The DPD [says](https://www.rae.es/dpd/hasta)

> Es muy frecuente que, cuando la oración principal tiene sentido negativo, en la subordinada aparezca un *no* expletivo, esto es, innecesario, como refuerzo de la negación de la oración principal: *No se fue hasta que no llegó su padre*; [...]. Debido a lo arraigado de este uso, ha de considerarse admisible, aunque no hay que olvidar que el enunciado no necesita esta segunda negación: *No se fue hasta que llegó su padre* [...].

So, when the main verb of the sentence is negative ("no comprendió"), the subordinate verb in the "hasta" clause is often negated, which is **acceptable but not necessary**. So you can also say

- no comprendió la razón hasta ver la curva de su vientre [...]

#### 3.

The NGLE [says in its §26.11n](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=peOczgOxbgJYDwxI):

> Se ha observado que las subordinadas de infinitivo que siguen a la preposición *hasta* designan a menudo una situación que se concibe como consecuencia, conclusión o desenlace natural de otra, como en *luchar hasta vencer* [...]

So "*hasta* + infinitive" is used normally to refer to an action or situation that is the **consequence** or the **conclusion** of the action denoted by the main verb. In your example, the subordinate "ver la curva de su vientre" concludes the situation "no comprender la razón" expressed by the main verb.

#### 4.

While it is true that *hasta* as a preposition usually introduces a noun (or something that acts as a noun), such as in

- No lo comprendí hasta el final de la clase

the sentence "no comprendió la razón hasta la vista de la curva de su vientre" sounds very strange. Probably because "hasta la vista" is a fixed, very common expression with a different meaning.

#### 5.

"Hasta que vio la curva" is the standard way of constructing subordinate clauses with "hasta", and always works.

#### 6.

"Hasta viendo la curva" is not correct. Differently from English, gerunds in Spanish cannot act as nouns.